# Redirecting form submission to URL after sending the details to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a popup newsletter signup. I already have the similar signup form in another page. I used the exact code and it works great. Once I submit the form, two actions has to happen.

1. Sending the form details to database
2. Redirecting to thank you page.

With the existing code(this is from a ecommerce website, I cannot manipulate the code), I can send the details to database - perfectly works fine, but 
it is not redirecting to Thank You page, instead redirecting to the page hardcoded in the database(assigned to "action". Is there a way out?

This is the code.

```
 <form name="MailingList" method="post" action="http://www.mywebsite.com/MailingList_subscribe.asp">  
     <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="28"> <br>
     <input type="submit" name="Submit"  value="Submit" width="260px">
 </form>
```

Instead of this - http://www.mywebsite.com/MailingList_subscribe.asp, I would like to redirect to "www.mywebsite/thankyou.html" . If I assign www.mywebsite.com/ThankYou.html to "action" , then the form is getting redirected to Thank you page, but not sending the information to the database. I have to use HTML, I cannot call from outside file. I guess I need to use PHP, but I am unclear with the code.

Sorry my mind is all over the place, I guess I explained it clearly. Apologies if my question is unclear. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Ajax form submission and then in success part redirect to thank you page?

Comment: can you edit MailingList_subscribe.php file?

Comment: I did add the code to the header, it didn't work, still directs me the  http://www.mywebsite.com/MailingList_subscribe.asp . I did use ID="formId". Is there any other solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I cannot edit MailingList_subscribe.php

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your form like `formId` and you can do this using jQuery,

Download the jQuery latest version from [JQuery repo](http://jquery.com/download/) and then place the jquery.min.js file in your resources folder.

**Updated**

```
<script src="yourResourcesFolderPath/jquery.min.js"></script>
// above code will use the jQuery plugin online
// chances are that the file path might be wrong according to where you put the js file
// A simple way to try this is put your file in the same folder of your html file and then change above code to
// <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> change file name according to downloaded file name.
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ // will run the below code after all html loaded 
        $('#formId').submit(function(){ // will be called upon form submission 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/MailingList_subscribe.asp",
                context: document.body
            }).success(function() { 
                // this will be called when you return from your server submit code
                location.href = "www.mywebsite.com/ThankYou.html";
            });
        });
    )};
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for such silly question. Where do I insert this and how do I call this in the above code. I am completely lost. Please guide.THanks

Comment: Ohh.. you can add this code in the '<head>' tag. Check the updated answer. I thought you are using jQuery. I will try to update the answer in javascript.

Comment: I am sorry, I have access to body tag only. I have to insert it in the body tag.

Comment: Then you have to handle this situation on server side. Find a way to redirect in PHP instead.

Comment: I did thought that, but there should be a way out with in HTML. Could you please explain your above code, I will try to see if I can insert in the header.

Comment: In order to run above code you first have to add the jQuery plugin in your html code. I will explain other things shortly if you can access the <head> tag.

Comment: I did add the jQuery plugin to my header. I did add your code <script>before </head> tag. I did assign formId to my form. But I am still getting the same result. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Please find if there are any console errors Using F12 key in your browser.

Comment: This is the code I have before </head> - 
  <script src="yourResourcesFolderPath/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#formId').submit(function(){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/MailingList_subscribe.asp",
                context: document.body
            }).success(function() { 
               
                location.href ="thank you.html";
            });
 });
    </script>
my errors: missing } after function body-refers to last }); before</script>-what & where should I add?

Comment: I did downloaded the Js and added to my folder and linked it as well. still getting the same result. :(